# Excel VBA - Delete rows when a cell contains a date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code that does the following:

- Finds Cell A4.
- If cell contains a date, delete the entire row.
- I want this to loop until the cell in column A does not contain a date. Once the cell is blank, the loop can end.

Comment: Is the cell in date form already, or could it be a string?

Comment: fwiw there are better ways speed wise to handle this than a For-loop over a range. `AutoFilter`, inserting a working column formula or using variant arrays are all vastly superior to looping over a range. If you are open to other methods let us know

Comment: Who gave this +1 ? There is not even a question in this post. It's just an affirmation that OP wants to do this (and did not try to do it or does not care to show his work).

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, there is a question. But from the looks of it he hasn't done any research whatsoever and probably has zilch for code.

Comment: @t.thielemans: There is no question here. First clue: look for a question mark. ;)

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, hmmm okay it's not really question, more of a demand for code! :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's all you need to do this:

> - Using the VBA function `IsDate`
> - If the value returned is true on the value in `Range A4`
> - Delete `entire row` of `Range A4`
> - If not then your sub is over.

Really it should not be much longer than 5-9 lines of code and it's all very very very simple. Come back if you have trouble writing the code **and ask a specific question about what you are having trouble with**.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, only cell A4 can't contain a date? I thought the entire column A! ;)